# Excel formula: Generate dynamic unique column list without slowdown?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a list of user-supplied values on `Sheet1` that I need to utilize in a drop-down on `Sheet2`. For this, I am attempting to generate a unique list on a hidden `Sheet3`. I have two named ranges:

```
 NonUniqueList - column with a user-supplied value (lets say B1:B1000)
 ContingentValue - column with a YES/NO dropdown (lets say C1:C1000)
```

In the list on the hidden `Sheet3`, I want all unique values from `NonUniqueList` for which the user has **not** selected "YES" in the `ContingentValue` named range. I have been able to successfully accomplish this using the formula below, which I paste into column A2:A1000 of hidden `Sheet3`:

`=IFERROR(""&INDEX(NonUniqueList,MATCH(0,IF(ContingentValue<>"YES",COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,NonUniqueList),""),0)),"")`

However, this formula appears to make the sheet quite sluggish when, for instance, deleting a value. Oftentimes taking several seconds. Is there a more efficient way of accomplishing my goal without the use of vba/macros? I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: You can use Advanced Filters, but no, with live formulas it is an array formula and will be slow depending on the amount of data and number of formulas.

Comment: Scott, is there a better way to integrate the ContingentValue<>YES check for improved performance? Can this be moved into the COUNTIF (in COUNTIFS form) as a second criteria, or does that not make any sense?

Comment: No just using formulas to create a unique list makes it an array formula.  It would speed it up a little if you did not care about the "Yes".  The COUNTIF() is imperative to create the unique list.  This is what vba is for.  Formulas, while powerful, have their limitations.

Comment: This may or may not help you but, make both `NonUniqueList` and `ContingentValue` as dynamic ranges (use `OFFSET` or `INDEX:INDEX`) since you may not use up all 1,000 rows.  And save the workbook as `.xlsb`.  Not sure how much this can help but hopefully it can speed up a little bit for you.